# Fortran Program of Strings: Counting commas

Tags: string, fortran

I am doing this assignment for my class and I don't know if I am doing it right.

The assignment is to design and implement a Fortran program to read a series of strings from the keyboard and count the commas (“,”) in each line.

The program should provide loops, formatted input/output, and processing strings.

The program should output the line number, the number of commas, and the first 70 characters of the input line.

Input will be terminated with a blank line or 9999 lines, whichever comes first.

Test the program on a series of different input values and verify that the output is correct for those input values. Assume the input string may be no longer than 999 characters.

Output shall be a formatted list of the format: 
nnnn:cc:aaaaaaaaaaaa…aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa where nnnn is the line number, cc is the comma count, and aaaaaaaaaaaa…aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa is the first 70 characters of the input line without trailing spaces.

This code for this program has to be simple enough for a beginner programmer to understand. Nothing complex.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Program counting
implicit none
     Integer :: line_number
      Integer :: comma_count
  Character (len = 999) :: message
WRITE (*,*)
WRITE (*,*)"Provide output the line number, the number of commas,&
            and the first 70 characters of the input line."
WRITE (*,*)

DO line_number = 0, 9999
        line_number = 1 + line_number
        IF (line_number == 0 .or. line_number >= 9999) then
        Exit
        END IF
WRITE (*,*)":"
        comma_count = 1 + line_number
WRITE (*,*)":"
WRITE (*,'(a70)') message
END DO
    READ  (*,*) line_number, comma_count, message
END Program counting
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. You haven't really asked a question, you just copied us ypur homework. What kind of problem do you have with this code? You have to tell us the details. If you have no problem and the code is working properly and you just wan't some feedback about your coding, then the question is off-topic and belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com  Please check their rules and read our page [ask] carefully to see how your question should look like and where does it belong.

Comment: did you not have some prior lessons where you learned a basic `do` loop? You cant modify the loop index inside the loop and i expect you are getting a pretty obvious error message about that.